# sqlite3, if it's not null, it's not 0, and it's not "", what is it?

Tags: select, sqlite, null, isnullorempty

In sqlite3, I've used the following syntax to insert rows into a table:

```
INSERT INTO schedule VALUES(some_date, (SELECT id_from_another_table WHERE where_clause));
```

What seems like the obvious assumption is that this embedded (SELECT ...) query will return a NULL when its result set is empty.

However, that does not seem to be the case...

```
sqlite> .schema schedule
CREATE TABLE schedule(date date, agent_id integer);

sqlite> select * from schedule;
2014-01-09|22
2014-01-09|
2014-01-09|23
2014-01-09|24
```

Notice how the second row is missing an entry for agent_id?

```
sqlite> select * from schedule where agent_id = null;
#nothing

sqlite> select * from schedule where agent_id = 0;
#nothing

sqlite> select * from schedule where agent_id = "";
#nothing

sqlite> select * from schedule where agent_id LIKE "% %";
#nothing
```

If that agent_id doesn't match null, "", 0, or anything with a space in it, what the heck is it?

Thanks in advance!  :-)

Comment: SQL `NULL` is a strange beast.  Like floating point `NaN` it is not equal to anything, not even itself, so you have to test for it using `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.

Comment: (well, that's not strictly true, the value of the expression `X = NULL` for any X is neither true nor false, it is itself `NULL`).

Comment: What you've said appears to be true.  Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all other DBs I've worked with the syntax would be `column IS NULL`. From what I can see it is the same in sqlite.

```
select * from schedule where agent_id IS NULL;
```